# PHP Regex Match Selected Pattern inside Div

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi i have large string in which it contains price i want to fetch the price string with price.

here is my code

```
$value=preg_match_all('/<div class=\"_productInfo\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/',$data,$estimates);
```

string contain many Div

```
<div class"_productInfo"> 2,200 Price </div>
```

i want to match the  string in this pattern and get data inside div

Comment: I think there is an error in your div. `class"_productInfo"` should be `class="_productInfo"`. Regexp: `/<div class="_productInfo">\s*(([0-9,]*)\s*price)\s*<\/div>/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling issue in your regex. You wrote `_prouctInfo` instead of `_productInfo`

```
$value = preg_match_all('/<div class=\"_productInfo\">\s+(([0-9,.]*?) Price)\s+<\/div>/', $data, $estimates);
```

[`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php) stored the found contents in the array `$estimates`. You can grab it via `$estimates[1][0]` for the first subpattern match **2,000 Price** and `$estimates[2][0]` holds only the price **2,000**.

Comment: sorry for spelling mistake it was typo.. actually above code is working but it  matching all <div class="productInfo">{any datalkljklj}</div> and i want to match only div contain this pattern  <div class="productInfo">2,200 price </div>

Comment: I have updated the regex. Know it should only match prices. Try it here: http://regexr.com/3dtb4

Comment: thank you very much  its working but only problem is . its only working when <div class="productInfo">{space} 2,200 price{spce} </div> on both side its not working with <div class="productInfo">2,200 price</div> without space on both side

Comment: @Allex what you mean with "its only working...". Do you mean the dot "."?

Comment: thanks i corrected it <div class=\"_productInfo\">(([0-9,]*?) price)<\div> by removing \s thank you very much its working

Comment: Ah, okay, i got it. I thought whitespaces are always there. You can switch from `\s+` to `\s*`. So a whitespace is not required anymore.